# I am unable to login Unity 8 desktop

Tags: 16.04, unity8

I have installed the unity8-desktop-session-mir package and logout, but no matter how I choose the Unity8, it is fail to login the desktop, it just stuck at the login screen, and I can do nothing but restart the lightdm.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the driver video? If yes, that is the problem. Mir doesn't work with proprietary drivers for now.

Comment: I have an Nvidia video card, and I didn't install the proprietary driver.